# Getting the address of a overwritten weak symbol

Tags: c, linker, weak-linking

My question assumes gcc or clang for x86 or x86_64.

Let's say I have the following files:

```c
// weak.c

#include <stdio.h>

__attribute__((weak))
void i_am_weak(void)
{
    printf("I am weak\n");
}

int main()
{
    i_am_weak();
    return 0;
}
```

```
// not_weak.c

#include <stdio.h>

void i_am_weak(void)
{
    printf("I am not weak\n");
}
```

If I compile just `weak.c`: `cc weak.c -o weak` and then I run it I get the message "I am weak". In turn, if I compile and link both: `cc weak.c not_weak.c` I get the message "I am not weak". Which is to be expected.

Can I somehow obtain the address of the weak symbol? Let's say that I want to invoke `i_am_weak` from `weak.c` from `not_weak.c`, similar to how I can use `__real_i_am_weak` from `__wrap_i_am_weak` when using the `--wrap` linker flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I somehow obtain the address of the weak symbol?

The usual technique is to use a strong internal symbol, to which `i_am_weak` is a weak alias ([documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void i_am_internal(void)
{
    printf("I am weak\n");
}

void i_am_weak(void) __attribute__((weak, alias("i_am_internal"))) 

int main()
{
    i_am_weak();
    i_am_internal();
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc weak.c && ./a.out
I am weak
I am weak

$ gcc weak.c not_weak.c && ./a.out
I am not weak
I am weak
```

You can now also take address of weak and non-weak symbols.

Comment: So if I had this situations https://pastebin.com/wZH7JZr7 and I wanted to replace `dependency_of_tested_function` during testing, but sometimes I'd want to control dynamically what function gets called I'd end up with something like this https://pastebin.com/7wTaCrkJ 

Thanks :)